# Windows 7: update error and can't access microsoft.com

Tags: windows-7

I just installed windows 7 and when I try to update windows it fails with the error 80072F76 and I think it is connected to the issue that I can't access microsoft.com (but all other websites), I only get a blank webpage (I tried it with different browser and it also works on other computers in the same network)

I ran a malwarecheck with malwarebytes and it didn't find anything, which was unlikely anyway since I just installed windows 7 and the only programs that I have installed are the drivers and firefox

I already tried:

- disabling the firewall
- several fix tools from microsoft
- flushing dns and stopping the DNS Client
- checked the host file
- turned windows defender on and off
- installed bit defender and checked the system, turned it on and off

I have no Idea what else I could do, especially since it is a brand new windows install, so I would really appreciate any ideas

(it is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/348283/cant-access-some-websites-with-any-browser) question, I also had the teredo tunneling interface for some reason, but disabling that didn't help either)

Answer (score 0):

May be a problem with the Windows update server since you say you can access other sites.

See [MS Windows 7 Error 80072f76](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Windows-Update-error-80072efe-or-80072f76)

Comment: Wait and try again. Or maybe just try choosing specific updates, instead of all of them at once.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.